# How to prove the following matrix is negative semi-definite matrix using Weyl's eigenvalue inequality and Rayleigh quotient?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a negative semi-definite matrix $A=\{a_{ij}\}_{i,j\in\{1,2,...,n\}}$,  how to prove the following two matrices are still a negative semi-definite, using Weyl's eigenvalue inequality and the concept of Rayleigh quotient?

The first matrix:

$\left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc|c}
 a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&\cdots&a_{1,n-1}&a_{1,n}&0\\
 a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&\cdots&a_{2,n-1}&a_{2,n}&0\\
 \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
    a_{n-1,1}&a_{n-1,2}&\cdots&a_{n-1,n-1}&a_{n-1,n}&0\\
 a_{n,1}&a_{n,2}&\cdots&a_{n-1,n}&a_{n,n}\color{red}{-1} &\color{red}{1}\\ \hline
    0     &0     &\cdots&0&\color{red}{1}    &\color{red}{-1} 
 \end{array}
 \right]
 $

The second matrix:

$\left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc|c}
 a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&\cdots&a_{1,n-1}&a_{1,n}&0\\
 a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&\cdots&a_{2,n-1}&a_{2,n}&0\\
 \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
    a_{n-1,1}&a_{n-1,2}&\cdots&a_{n-1,n-1}&a_{n-1,n}&0\\
 a_{n,1}&a_{n,2}&\cdots&a_{n-1,n}&a_{n,n}\color{red}{+1}&\color{red}{-1}\\ \hline
    0     &0     &\cdots&0&\color{red}{-1}    &\color{red}{1} 
 \end{array}
 \right]
 $

Comment: The first matrix is negative semidefinite because the sum of negative semidefinite matrices must be negative semidefinite. The second matrix might not be negative semidefinite.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you. The second matrix is actually also negative semi-definite, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: In fact, the second matrix cannot possibly be negative semidefinite: if we take $x = (0,\dots,0,1)^T$, then $x^TMx > 0$. Why do you believe that the matrix **is** negative semidefinite?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I re-checked, yes, the second one is not $\leq 0$. Is it possible to prove the first one using Weyl's eigenvalue inequality and the concept of Rayleigh quotient? Maybe this makes things complicated but just want to understand something in the paper..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove that the first matrix is negative semidefinite as follows. Note that the matrix can be expressed as $M = A + B$, where
$$
A =
\left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc|c}
 a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&\cdots&a_{1,n-1}&a_{1,n}&0\\
 a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&\cdots&a_{2,n-1}&a_{2,n}&0\\
 \vdots&\cdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
    a_{n-1,1}&a_{n-1,2}&\cdots&a_{n-1,n-1}&a_{n-1,n}&0\\
 a_{n,1}&a_{n,2}&\cdots&a_{n-1,n}&a_{n,n}&0\\ \hline
    0     &0     &\cdots&0&0   &0
 \end{array}
 \right],\\
B = 
\left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc|c}
 0&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
 0&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
 \vdots&\cdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
    0&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
 0&0&\cdots&0&-1&1\\ \hline
    0     &0     &\cdots&0&1    &-1
 \end{array}
 \right].
$$
It is clear that these matrices are negative semidefinite. With the Rayleigh quotient, we can see that
$$
\begin{align*}
\lambda_{\max}(A + B) &= \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{x^T(A + B)x}{x^Tx}
= \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} + \frac{x^TBx}{x^Tx}
\\ &= \max_{x \neq 0, y \neq 0, x = y} \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} + \frac{y^TBy}{y^Ty}
\\ & \leq \max_{x \neq 0, y \neq 0} \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} + \frac{y^TBy}{y^Ty}
\\ & = \max_{x \neq 0}\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} + \max_{y \neq 0} \frac{y^TBy}{y^Ty}
= \lambda_{\max}(A) + \lambda_{\max}(B) \leq 0 + 0 = 0.
\end{align*}
$$
So, $A + B$ is indeed symmetric with non-positive eigenvalues.

That said, there's no need to invoke the Rayleigh quotient: for the **definition** of negative semidefinite, we need to show that $x^T(A + B)x \leq 0$ for all $x$. With that, merely note that for all $x$, we have
$$
x^T(A + B)x = x^TAx + x^TBx \leq 0 + 0 = 0,
$$
where we use the fact that $A$ and $B$ are negative semidefinite.